Firebase, user deleted but still present with: Auth.auth().currentUser
First I signed up, then I logged in and everything works fine.
After I deleted the user from Firebase, but then strangely when I run this code:
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        
        guard user != nil else {
            welcomeLabel.text = languageFile.keyLabelWelcome
            return
        }
        
        welcomeLabel.text = languageFile.keyLabelWelcomeBack + " " + (user?.email ?? "")

it shows me the email of the deleted user, but it's not possible, the user no longer exists!
Instead what it should do is execute the keyLabelWelcome code, instead it executes the keyLabelWelcomeBack code.
how do you check if user exists or not exist in firebase Authentication?
UPDATE
I get it, Firebase has cache memory issues. I solved it like this:
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        reloadUser()
        
    }

func reloadUser(_ callback: ((Error?) -> ())? = nil){
            Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload(completion: { (error) in
                callback?(error)
            })
        }


If you want to answer your own question, that's fine.  But don't edit your post to include the answer.  Just answer it using the normal answering mechanism to make it clear to future readers that you found a solution.
